# Sort of Excel files

Tags: powershell

I am having the script to sort the excel data to descending order format and I need to save the data to another location. But while executing the below script error is showing.

```
Import-Csv -Path D:\Excel\details.csv | Sort-Object AMCore Content Version | Export-Csv D:\sb.csv
```

[image: CSV Input data]

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from an unquoted argument, [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.2) is binding `AMCore` positionally as argument for the `-Property` parameter and has no clue on what to do with `Content` as the next argument.

```bash
... | Sort-Object 'AMCore Content Version' | ...
```

The above will be syntactically correct, however that's not enough to do a proper sorting on these **Values**, it would require an [*expression script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2#notes) which would convert each value to either [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-6.0) or [`double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=net-6.0) to do proper sorting:

```bash
Import-Csv -Path D:\Excel\details.csv |
    Sort-Object { [double] $_.'AMCore Content Version' } |
        Export-Csv D:\sb.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You can find an example below for testing:

```bash
$details = @'
AMCore Content Version
2.5
1.5
1
0.5
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$details | Sort-Object { [double] $_.'AMCore Content Version' }
```